# can I ask my question in programmers.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, support, on-topic-definition, site-rec

I want to know, How to do the following in program ?
I am looking for logic/algorithm so that, I can implement it.

I want to split the joined & wrongly spelled words to give a correct result ?

```
Wrongly spelled & joined word
fasewash ==> face wash
charginglight => charging light
andraidphones => android phones
```

I have set of words (dictionary) and perfectly working spell suggestion when there is a spelling mistake.
for example, when you input "wach", spell suggestion will give "wash" correctly.

How can I do it grammatically ? 
I am not able to get any idea about implementing the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is research important?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important)

Answer (score 3):

The current version of the question you have posed would probably be closed as too broad. If you search for [How to write a spelling corrector](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=how+to+write+a+spelling+corrector&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) you will find numerous tutorials and approaches based on this including a rather complete coverage of the topic at [How to Write a Spelling Corrector](http://www.norvig.com/spell-correct.html).

There are numerous bits out there about the [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) and similar concepts.

You need to try to explain your algorithm and what isn't working. In the question show that you are familiar enough with the terms and concepts of a spelling corrector so that people are not repeating what you already know and also not going much deeper in the topic than your understanding of the subject.

Yes, it can be on topic - but you need to make sure that you not going to ask a question where there are 50 possible answers, or the answer that you really want is 50 pages long.

Comment: In a way the question might not be about the whole area of spelling correction but just about a particular aspect, the division of wrongly spelled words which are combinations of single words. I wonder how much more one would need to reduce the problem until it becomes not "too broad" anymore.